# how do I say "If a string contains "x" in PHP?

Tags: php, string, offset

I have a variable:

```
$testingAllDay = $event->when[0]->startTime;
```

This variable will be this format if it is "All Day":

```
2011-06-30
```

It will be this format if it is not "All Day":

```
2011-07-08T12:00:00.000-05:00
```

I'm wanting to do something like:

```
if ($testingAllDay does not contain "T"){
   $AllDay = 1;
   } else {
   $AllDay = 0;
}
```

Do I need to use a `strstr()` here, or is there another function that does this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [strpos](http://www.php.net/strpos) to see if the 'T' character is present in the string as follows:

```
if (strpos($testingAllDay, 'T') !== false) {
    // 'T' was present in $testingAllDay
}
```

That said, it would probably be faster/more efficient (although no doubt meaninglessly so) to use [strlen](http://www.php.net/strlen) in this case, as according to your example, the time-free field will always be 10 characters long.

For example:

```
if(strlen($testingAllDay) > 10) {
    // 'T' was present in $testingAllDay
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Learned a new one!

Comment: Yeah-I think I prefer strpos because it just seems less dependent on specific stringlength, etc.

Comment: @Joel True - it's the right thing to do in terms of a solution and will be considerably more obvious (in terms of legibility) in six months time than a strlen would be. Good call, that man. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use strpos:

```
if (strpos($testingAllDay,"T")!==false){
```

or strstr

```
if (!strstr($testingAllDay,"T")){
```

Comment: What if `T` is the first character?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strpos($testingAllDay, 'T') !== FALSE){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If those are the only possible cases, even [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen) will do.

Answer (score 1):

not exactly answer to the question, but you could check with strlen().
i.e. "All Day" length is 10, anything above that is not.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `strpos()`. The following is an example picking up your wording for the variable names even:

```
$testingAllDayTPosition = strpos($testingAllDay, 'T');

$testingAllDayDoesNotContainT = false === $testingAllDayTPosition;

if ($testingAllDayDoesNotContainT){
   $AllDay = 1;
   } else {
   $AllDay = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strstr and strpos are two functions by which you can complete your requirement.

strstr will see if substring exists in string and it will echo from first occurrence of string to rest.

While strpos will give you position of first occurrence of the string.